# How can we add a parameter so that a user select the jenkins node in groovy scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

We have two nodes say "Node1" and "Node2".Currently we are running 'mapping.groovy' job on "Node1" by mentioning the node name in the code like below:

node('Node1')

and then pipeline follows. Now we got another node "Node2". We want to run the 'mapping.groovy' job on Node2 also. So how can a user select the node (either Node1 or Node2) to run the above job.
Thanks in advance,

I thought that I can use “Parameters” Option in “Build with Parameters” option Jenkins Build. But I have no idea on this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to parameterize your build.  This looks something like the following:

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   parameters {
      choice(
           name: 'NODE_NAME', 
           choices: ['Node1', 'Node2']
           description: 'The name of the node you want to run the job on.'
      )
   }
}
```

That will force whomever kicks off the job to select the node you want them to use.

BUT, since we're talking about node selection you may consider how you can have that job pick the node itself using the `agent` command above.  The whole purpose of `agent` is to match various nodes with job demands, and that enables the job to be self assigning and enables automation of job execution vs someone manually running the job.  Of course this all depends on the specifics of your situation which I don't know, but something to consider.